# Unexpected output of Exception Handling

Tags: java

Can you please tell me what is wrong with my code. It is supposed to ask for input until both inputs entered are integers

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    int a, b;
    Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
    int i = 0;

    while (i == 0) {
        try {

            System.out.print("Enter first number");
            a = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number you entered is " + a);
            System.out.println("Enter second number");
            b = input.nextInt();
            System.out.println("The number you entered is " + b);

            i++;
        } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
    System.out.println("End");
}
```

Comment: Think about implementing a method that requests a single integer (and it should ask again if the input was invalid). Then call this method twice. This is much easier, than requesting and checking two valid individual numbers. Also the user doesn't need to re-enter the first number, if the second one was invalid.

Answer (score 2):

If an invalid integer is entered that content will remain in the input buffer and be passed through to the exception block ad infinitum. These invalid characters need to be consumed using [`next`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#next--) or [`nextLine`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#nextLine--). [`hasNextInt`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Scanner.html#hasNextInt--) should be used to check that an integer is actually available before calling `nextInt`

Answer (score -1):

Your Looping condition is :

```
int i = 0;
while (i == 0) {  // Looping against i==0
    try {
        System.out.print("Enter first number");
        a = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number you entered is " + a);
        System.out.println("Enter second number");
        b = input.nextInt();
        System.out.println("The number you entered is " + b);
        i++; // Increments the value of i to 1, which makes the loop to exit after first iteration
    } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Refactor your code as :

```
boolean areBothIntegers = true;
        while (areBothIntegers) {
            try {
                System.out.print("Enter first number");
                a = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("The number you entered is " + a);
                System.out.println("Enter second number");
                b = input.nextInt();
                System.out.println("The number you entered is " + b);
            } catch (InputMismatchException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
                areBothIntegers = false;
            }
        }
```

**Sample Output :**

Enter first number : 10

The number you entered is 10

Enter second number : 21

The number you entered is 21

Enter first number : 21

The number you entered is 21

Enter second number : 34

The number you entered is 34

Enter first number : 21.5  // Not an int value, so throws the exception and exits

```
java.util.InputMismatchException
    at java.util.Scanner.throwFor(Scanner.java:909)
    at java.util.Scanner.next(Scanner.java:1530)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2160)
    at java.util.Scanner.nextInt(Scanner.java:2119)
    at jdbc.statements.ADS.main(ADS.java:15)
```

Comment: @Tom Yes it does..after then only i posted this.

Comment: And this code asks the user for input until he entered two valid numbers?

Comment: `It is supposed to ask for input until both inputs entered are integers` That is what OP tries to accomplish. Your loop asks for more input as long the user enters numbers. This is the direct opposite.

Comment: It actually asks for input as long as both inputs are valid, however I got the point .. respect!

Comment: @Tom, in my view what OP tries to accomplish is to ask for inputs until both are valid int values. If he had tried for only one pair of i/p's then why he would have to use while loop at all..?

Comment: @ElioNushi, if this what you intended to do and if find this solution acceptable, then accept it as answer

Comment: @AmiteshRai Yes, he want to loop until both values are valid integers. Your loop doesn't do that. It fails if one input is invalid.

Comment: @Armitesh Your view is right but your code does not reflect your view

Comment: @Tom, then i'm curious to see how would you do that.?

Comment: Why should I invest time in solving this question just because you misunderstood it? Even OP already told you that.